# backup MS SQL Server db from linked server

Tags: sql-server

I have two system (A,B) on network and i want to make sql backup from A into B storage.
both system ham sql 2008 up and running.
I added linked server of A DB into B management Studio
But The Following command Give me error.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [10.45.2.63].[DB] TO  DISK = N'E:\BackUp\60\DB.BK' 
-- COMPAC RAR
DECLARE @SERVER VARCHAR(100), @COMMAND VARCHAR(100), @FILE VARCHAR(100)
SET @SERVER = @@SERVERNAME
SET @COMMAND = 'E:\BackUp\RAR\RAR.exe A E:\BackUp\60\' + @SERVER + '_BASE.RAR E:\BackUp\60\DB.BK' 
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL @COMMAND
-- EXCLUIR FILE BACKUP
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'DEL E:\BackUp\60\DB.BK'
```

i have no problem for selecting data from [10.45.2.63].[DB] , but cant backing it up in B machine.

In above query sql gives error on "[10.45.2.63]" and didnt recognise it as a linked server.

Comment: I assume your linked server is called `[10.45.2.63]` (this information is handy to know). To execute something remote on a linked  server you use `OPENQUERY`, although I don't know if it'll work with `BACKUP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, without an error message, how can we help except to through some stuff at the wall and see what sticks???

When you create a linked server, you give it the credentials to use when connecting to the remote server. Start here, do these credential have the ability to perform a backup?

Second, you said you are backing up to the storage of server B, so I assume "E" is a mapped drive? If so, first use a UNC, instead of mapped drive letter. Drive letters are **User Specific** (IE. //10.45.2.64/ShareName) Second, do the credentials of the linked server have access from the one server to the other to write the backup? Remember, you are telling the other server to do a backup, your are NOT doing the backup on the remote server.

What you should do is start on the server you are trying to backup and test there using these credential, then work your way OUT until it all works. And most of all, POST YOUR ERRORS!

Comment: thanks for respond , yes i think the credentials is ok becuase i have no problem for select query.
the problem is if i put "BACKUP DATABASE" before [10.45.2.63] the linked server name goes undefiend , but if i use "Select * from "[10.45.2.63]" it works :|

Comment: Being able to "READ" data is a whole lot different from being able to perform a backup of a database. Just because you can do one, in NO WAY means you can do the other. It's like saying I know I would be a great singer, just because I can ride a bike.

Comment: so i guess linked server not working exactly like local server(some limitation). The "E" letter was physical drive on Server B. i guess that was the problem

Comment: You need to think about this in a different way. When you are on your computer in SSMS and you run a SELECT statement or backup, you are TELLING the server to do something and everything (drives, folders, security) is based on what is on that server. When you tell another server (through linked servers) to do something, you are telling that linked server to do something. Nothing is happening on the local computer or on the first server.